# MemberExpression is marked as Convert(...) call instead of MemberExpression

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm currently facing an issue with using Reflection on custom types. I have a method with the following signature:

```
protected static bool ReplacePropertyValue<TTargetResource, TValue>(TEntity entity, TResourcePatch resourcePatch, Expression<Func<TResource, TTargetResource>> sourceResourcePropertyExpression, Expression<Func<TTargetResource, TValue>> sourcePropertyExpression, Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> targetPropertyExpression)
```

where `TEntity` is the database-entity I want to update.
where `TTargetResource` is the resource of the patch-document I want the new value from.
where `TValue` is the type of the property I want the new value from to be set in the entity.

`resourcePatch` contains all the patch-instructions I want to apply to the `entity`.
`sourceResourcePropertyExpression` is the expression for the resource with the new/changed value.
`sourcePropertyExpression` is the expression to the resource's property with the new/changed value.
`targetPropertyExpression` is the expression pointing to the property which should have the new/changed value.

However I am facing an issue where the `targetPropertyExpression` is not a `MemberExpression`. Below is the call of the method

```
 ReplacePropertyValue(theEntity, resourcePatch, team => team.ParentTeam, pt => pt.Id, team => team.TeamParentTeamId)
```

However, the last param is shown as `{team => Convert(team.TeamParentTeamId)}` and I don't get the point why. `TeamParentTeamId` is of type `Guid`.
When used with another property of type `Guid?` it works as expected.

Can anyone tell me why the first one (`Guid`) is a `Convert(...)`-expression?

Answer (score 2):

Because both expression needs to return `TValue`. In your case, there is an expression that returns `Guid` and one that returns `Guid?`. Since you can implicitly convert a struct to its nullable version, `TValue` can be `Guid?` with a implicit conversion applied on top of the property selector that return `Guid`.